# Partitioning issue with sgdisk

Tags: linux

I am trying to partition hard disk using sgdisk. After running the sgdisk partitioning commands i can see that the gpt partition table is getting created but the logical partitions are not getting created. Below are the commands i used.

## sgdisk -og /dev/sda

Creating new GPT entries.

sda: sda1

The operation has completed successfully.

## sgdisk -n 1:2048:264191 -c 1:"kernel" /dev/sda

Setting name!

partNum is 0

REALLY setting name!

sda: sda1

The operation has completed successfully.

## sgdisk -n 2:264192:395263 -c 2:"rootfs" /dev/sda

Setting name!

partNum is 1

REALLY setting name!

sda: sda1

The operation has completed successfully.

## sgdisk -n 3:395263:460799 -c 3:"data" /dev/sda

Information: Moved requested sector from 395263 to 395264 in
order to align on 2048-sector boundaries.

Setting name!

partNum is 2

REALLY setting name!

sda: sda1
The operation has completed successfully.

## sgdisk -p /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB

Logical sector size: 512 bytes

Disk identifier (GUID): 1FE36D38-3427-40CC-A0B0-08664DC76C74
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries

Total free space is 3906570349 sectors (1.8 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          264191   128.0 MiB   8300  kernel

2          264192          395263   64.0 MiB    8300  rootfs

3          395264          460799   32.0 MiB    8300  data

## cat /proc/partitions

major minor  #blocks  name

8        0 1953514584 sda

8        1 1953514583 sda1

## lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk

`-sda1   8:1    0   1.8T  0 part

I am using sgdisk version 0.8.10. I am doing this test on an ARM A9 board using initrd image.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to enable EFI_PARTITION in kernel configuration. With this enabled the issue is fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to enable CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION in linux kernel config.

make linux-menuconfig 
Enable the block layer –> Partition Types -> Select “EFI GUID Partition Support”

With this able to see partitions created are written to disk...

Also there is another setting need to be looked, if you are in plan of creating more than 8 partitions.

```
│ Symbol: MMC_BLOCK_MINORS [=8] │
│ Type : integer │
│ Range : [4 256] │
│ Prompt: Number of minors per block device │
│ Defined at drivers/mmc/card/Kconfig:17 │
│ Depends on: MMC [=y] && MMC_BLOCK [=y] │
│ Location: │
│ -> Device Drivers │
│ -> MMC/SD/SDIO card support (MMC [=y]) │
│ -> MMC block device driver (MMC_BLOCK [=y])
```

Changing the value will support upto 256 partitions...